# Regex deny special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, special-characters, regex-negation

How can i deny Turkish characters inside regex set.i want to show an alert if an user enter this letters **ÜüŞşİıĞğÇçÖö**.I am using jquery.ValidationEngine.js  an specified set as follow.Could you please help me?

```
"email": {"regex":
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/gi,
"alertText": "* Invalid e-mail address"}
```

Comment: I'd rather use an email address validation pattern. You can find a lot of them...
Otherwise you can find a full manual of regex (including js regex, unicode characters and everything else) [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Only that handful of Turkish characters? What about the hundreds of thousands of other "special" characters a user may enter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follow.

> /^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+.)*\w[\w-]{0,66}).([a-z]{2,6}(?:.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@[?((25[0-5].|2[0-4][0-9].|1[0-9]{2}.|[0-9]{1,2}.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}).){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})]?$)/i